# random index of CuArray with condition in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, gpu

Suppose I have a CuArray with random zeros and ones and I want to get a random index of CuArray corresponding to value one. For instance,

```
m = 100;
A = CuArray(rand([0, 1], m));
i = rand(1:m); 
while A[i]!=1
    i = rand(1:m); 
end
```

Is there a function so that I can not use while looping?

Answer (score 2):

Your construction of `A` has the following equivalent representation:

```
using Distributions
n_ones = rand(Binomial(m, 0.5))
one_inds = shuffle(1:m)[1:n_ones]
A = zeros(Int, m)
A[one_inds] .= 1
```

That is, you first choose the number of ones you are going to set (from a binomial distribution, since you have `m` independent choices), and then select without repetition that many indices (by just taking the init of all indices, shuffled).

Written this way, choosing a random index of a one is just

```
rand(one_inds)
```